# Different versions of Lightweight Grid and installed Mathematica

Tags: lightweight-grid, grid-mathematica

I am a beginner in the use of [LightWeightGrid](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/LightweightGridClient/tutorial/Introduction.html.en), but I wanted to connect some servers on which Mathematica is installed.

There are some old Linux machines (Mathematica version: 8.0) and relatively new Windows Server machines (Mathematica version: 11.3).

After installation of `LightWeightGrid` manager, I found that I cannot launch lightweight grid kernels on latter Windows Server machines.

This is the error code:

> RemoteKernelOpen::lwgresponse: Received an unexpected response from ***(local IP).  Check that the hostname or URL is correct and corresponds to a compatible Lightweight Grid Manager server.

First, I can access ***:3737 (Manager Web Interface), so the connection is established (this error is not `RemoteKernelOpen::connect` that is listed on [user guide](http://media.wolfram.com/documents/WolframLightweightGridManager.pdf) pdf).

I don't know what causes this, but as a test, I tried to launch a kernel on the Windows Server machine via the Web Interface.

As a result the kernel was launched successfully, but I noticed it says 8.0 as its Mathematica version:

[image]

However, as I mentioned, the true Mathematica version on its machine is 11.3.

Is it the reason for the error??

---

By the way, I think LightWeightGrid is too old. Is there any alternative way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Lightweight Grid is delivered as an optional add-on to a version of Mathematica, bundled into a gridMathematica installer. However, by using the Services feature, you can get the same agent to launch any version of Mathematica installed on the machine.

When you went into the web interface and launched a kernel on-demand, and it showed Mathematica version 8.0, that showed that it is pretty old.

Unfortunately for this scheme, you can't separate the agent installer from the Mathematica installer, but you can fix it up after the fact.

If you go into the Services tab and edit the configuration for the General service (or create a new service, called it `11.3`) you can point it to a different kernel path than the one it was set up for. I can't guarantee 100% that the MathLink in version 8 will talk to your 11.3 kernels, but if it were me that's what I'd do.

If that doesn't work, I'd work on getting a more recent gridMathematica installer, because 8.0 is pretty old by now (as you said).